# The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found(WPF)

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core

I have been trying to load the project on my laptop and it keeps saying "The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found" here is my code from project.json

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs">
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Properties\Resources.resx">
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

what should I change here to make it work? I have dotnet 8.0.100 installed.

I tried reinstalling dotnet SDK and VS 2022 same thing keeps occurring.

Comment: That Project is old. Probably an *ancient* Preview version, as is `project.json`, which is now part of the `.csproj`  file. You have to migrate your Project to the SDK style

Comment: how can i do this?

Comment: @tersawy please check my answer. Just a reminder, does my answer help you? If it doesn't help, please comment on my answer. Long period of open question with answers that has no marked answer will not help others.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is quite obvious. You said that you want to have WPF but your csproj says otherwise, and it uses WindowsForms only:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

In order to use WPF, please replace that line of `<UseWindowsForms>` to use WPF. Update the line and use `<UseWPF>`, so that line should be:

```
   <UseWPF>true<UseWPF>
```

**NOTE:**
you can also still use both WindowsForms and WPF, but then this is quite advanced topics.
See also this doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props-desktop